# Android Studio, drawable is only available in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio

So I have a drawable that I am using in my project - it is a .png file I created using Aseprite, and I have quite a few of them. Some of the first ones I added seem to not be flagged as debug only, but many of the later ones are tagged as such. Attached is an example image of what I am talking about - is there any way to change the image to be available in release as well?
[image: debug_only]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added the drawable to use only in debug mode.Move that image to drawable root. Or Refactor > Move file and change the directory as follows (base directory of Drawable)

[image]